# Problema con return node js

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express

Tengo una aplicación express con mongodb, me solicitaron dividir la lógica de la base de datos de la lógica de las rutas, cree un "controlador" para que maneje esa sección sin estar en contacto con el req y res de la ruta. El problema es que no logro retornar ningún valor después de que se hace la inserción en la base de datos

Adjunto los códigos, controlador

```
accountctlr.createAccount = function(newAccount){
     var response = false;
    Account.create(newAccount, function(err,newlyCreated){
        if(err){     
            console.log(err);
            //return err;
        }
        else{
           console.log("account added");
           response = true;
           console.log(response);
           return response;
       }
    });
}

module.exports = accountctlr;
```

Codigo de la ruta

```
 router.post("/",function(req,res){

  var dbResponse =  accountctlr.createAccount( {name:req.body.name});
  console.log(dbResponse);

 });
```

Después que ingreso el dato, no regresa el valor para utilizarlo en el modulo de rutas, al revisar la base de datos si hay un insert en la db pero no logro obtener un valor de vuelta, alguna sugerencia???

Comment: `res.send()` o `res.json()` para retornar datos. https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res

Comment: La idea es que el controlador no interactua con req o res, mi idea es retornar un boolean y manejar el res en la logica en la seccion de ruta pero la insercion en el controlador

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido @Marco Marichal,

El problema que te surge es motivo de que no estas devolviendo la respuesta de la consulta 'Account.create()' ya que realizando el 'return' no la devolverá, tendrías que realizarlo mediante 'callbacks'.

Te muestro la solución que yo implementaría:
Controlador:

```
accountctlr.createAccount = function(newAccount, callback){ //Añadimos el callback
     var response = false;
    Account.create(newAccount, function(err,newlyCreated){
        if(err){     
            console.log(err);
            //return err;
        }
        else{
           console.log("account added");
           response = true;
           console.log(response);
           callback(response) // Aqui devolveria la respuesta de la consulta.
       }
    });
}
```

Endpoint de express:

```
router.post("/",function(req,res){

  accountctlr.createAccount({name:req.body.name},function(response){
    console.log(dbResponse);//Aqui trabajaria con la reuesta para devolverla con el Response de Express
  });
 });
```

Prueba con esta solución y afirmamos si te funciona ya que el código mostrado debería de funcionar

Un saludo

Comment: Hola dispculpas por responder tan tarde, la solucion esta correcta, muchas gracias me ayudo demasiado